# What does red and yellow horizontal bar mean in Android Profile GPU rendering

Tags: android, performance, android-studio

I am trying to profile gpu rendering for my app. The [official doc](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/rendering/inspect-gpu-rendering) mentions only about vertical bars and I am not able to get any reference on yellow and red horizontal bars.

I got to know from [official doc](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/rendering/inspect-gpu-rendering) that the horizontal green line represents 16 milliseconds and to achieve 60 frames per second, the vertical bar for each frame needs to stay below this line. But as shown in the image below from my app, I couldn't find anything about yellow and red horizontal bars.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

green is 16 ms frame - 60 frames per second

yellow is 21 ms frame - 47 frames per second

red is 31 ms frame - 32 frames per second

Comment: Hey @hitrain Do you have any source from where you got this values? Could you add that?

Comment: no, calculated. these are approximate cutoffs of the frame time. larger column, longer frame time, color cues and landmark

Comment: So when device has faster screen than 60Hz, I would assume that these horizontal lines equally apply to the 100%, 75% and 50% of the frame time?

For example, if device runs at 90 fps, it would mean 90 fps, 67 fps, 45 fps?